# java.lang.Object to arraylist

Tags: java, json, type-conversion, gson

Is there a way I can parse / transform this kind of java.lang.object into and array or List of java.lang.Object:

```
[
    {procedure_name_txt=nameText, procedure_name_ets_id=ID-1234, procedure_ets_desc=description_123}, 
    {procedure_name_txt=deafness, procedure_name_ets_id=ID-99022, procedure_ets_desc=description_31222}
]
```

Already tried using Gson but unfortunately the object format is not on json form.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's not JSON: no double quotes on keys/values; and = instead of :

Comment: @john thanks, comment deleted

Answer (score 1):

The document you've provided is **not** a valid JSON for several reasons:

- The array element keys are not enclosed in quotes `"`.
- The array element key/value pairs are not delimited with `:`, but are delimited `=`.
- The string values are not enclosed in quotes `"`.

I'm almost sure the document is actually a pretty-printed `toString` result of a collection/array whose elements are either maps or POJOs with `toString` overridden. Such output is **never** meant to be parsed programmatically. However, Gson, can parse the "tostring" result due its simplicity violating the JSON format grammar and being tooooo lenient.

```java
private static final String LOOKS_LIKE_JSON = "[\n" +
        "    {procedure_name_txt=nameText, procedure_name_ets_id=ID-1234, procedure_ets_desc=description_123}, \n" +
        "    {procedure_name_txt=deafness, procedure_name_ets_id=ID-99022, procedure_ets_desc=description_31222}\n" +
        "]";

//  private static final Type procedureListType = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, Procedure.class).getType();
private static final Type procedureListType = new TypeToken<List<Procedure>>() {
}.getType();

//  private static final Type procedureArrayType = Procedure[].class;
private static final Type procedureArrayType = new TypeToken<Procedure[]>() {
}.getType();

private static final Type stringToStringMapListType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>() {
}.getType();

private static final Type stringToStringMapArrayType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>[]>() {
}.getType();

private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
private static final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

public static void main(final String... args) {
    final List<Procedure> procedureList = gson.fromJson(LOOKS_LIKE_JSON, procedureListType);
    System.out.println(procedureList);
    final Procedure[] procedureArray = gson.fromJson(LOOKS_LIKE_JSON, procedureArrayType);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(procedureArray));
    final List<Map<String, String>> mapList = gson.fromJson(LOOKS_LIKE_JSON, stringToStringMapListType);
    System.out.println(mapList);
    final Map<String, String>[] mapArray = gson.fromJson(LOOKS_LIKE_JSON, stringToStringMapArrayType);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mapArray));
    final JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(LOOKS_LIKE_JSON);
    System.out.println(jsonElement);
}
```

Where the `Procedure` class is as follows:

```java
final class Procedure {

    @SerializedName("procedure_name_txt")
    final String name = null;

    @SerializedName("procedure_name_ets_id")
    final String id = null;

    @SerializedName("procedure_ets_desc")
    final String description = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Procedure{")
                .append("name='").append(name).append('\'')
                .append(", id='").append(id).append('\'')
                .append(", description='").append(description).append('\'')
                .append('}')
                .toString();
    }

}
```

Output:

- IntelliJ IDEA-generated `Procedure.toString`:

> [Procedure{name='nameText', id='ID-1234', description='description_123'}, Procedure{name='deafness', id='ID-99022', description='description_31222'}]

- list of maps of string to string entries (actually this reflects the given input), JDK `toString()`:

> [{procedure_name_txt=nameText, procedure_name_ets_id=ID-1234, procedure_ets_desc=description_123}, {procedure_name_txt=deafness, procedure_name_ets_id=ID-99022, procedure_ets_desc=description_31222}]

- Gson JSON tree model `toString()`:

> [{"procedure_name_txt":"nameText","procedure_name_ets_id":"ID-1234","procedure_ets_desc":"description_123"},{"procedure_name_txt":"deafness","procedure_name_ets_id":"ID-99022","procedure_ets_desc":"description_31222"}]